# Having trouble with json_normalize and multiple record_path values

Tags: python, json, pandas

Apologies if this question has been asked before. I am new to pandas and I am trying to flatten a nested API response to tabular format with json_normalize().I am having problems figuring out how to put different nests in the in the record_path parameter.My current code keeps displaying `result = result[spec]KeyError: 'Type'`

I'm at a bit of a loss on what to try or where to look next. Thank you.

**Desired Output:**

```
  Count     Metric  Title   Platform   Begin_Date   End_Date        Type         Value
   1    Total_Req   AACN      OVID     2019-01-01   2019-02-28    Print_ISSN  1234-5678
```

**Code Snip:**

```
    try:
    # get data from vendors
    data =json.loads(response.text)

    print("Processing Data....")
    table = json_normalize(data['Report_Items'][0],record_path =[
        'Performance','Instance','Item_ID'], meta=['Title','Platform',['Performance','Period','Begin_Date'],['Item_ID','Type'],['Performance','Period','End_Date'],'Publisher',,errors='ignore',record_prefix = "Test_",sep ='_')
    table.to_html('october_stats.html')# output to a html file
    table.to_excel('annual_stats.xlsx', sheet_name = 'NE_Stats')#output to Excel file
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    print(data, "This is not a JSON format..")  # catch vendor JSON errors
```

**JSON Snip**

```
    {
   'Title':'AACN Advanced Critical Care',
   'Item_ID':[
      {
         'Type':'Print_ISSN',
         'Value':'1559-7768'
      },
      {
         'Type':'Proprietary',
         'Value':'Ovid:01256961'
      }
   ],
   'Platform':'OvidMD',
   'Publisher':'American Association of Critical Care Nurses',
   'Publisher_ID':[
      {
         'Type':'Proprietary',
         'Value':'Ovid:21790'
      }
   ],
   'Performance':[
      {
         'Period':{
            'Begin_Date':'2019-02-01',
            'End_Date':'2019-02-28'
         },
         'Instance':[
            {
               'Metric_Type':'Total_Item_Requests',
               'Count':1
            },
            {
               'Metric_Type':'Unique_Item_Requests',
               'Count':1
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to manipulate this a bit as your expected output doesn't match with your sample json snip, but this could get you going:

```
data =json.loads(response.text)

def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
    flatten(y)
    return out


flat = flatten_json(data)


results = pd.DataFrame()
special_cols = []

columns_list = list(flat.keys())
for item in columns_list:
    try:
        row_idx = re.findall(r'\_(\d+)\_', item )[0]
    except:
        special_cols.append(item)
        continue
    column = re.findall(r'\_\d+\_(.*)', item )[0]
    column = column.replace('_', '')

    row_idx = int(row_idx)
    value = flat[item]

    results.loc[row_idx, column] = value

for item in special_cols:
    results[item] = flat[item]
```

**Output:**

```
print (results.to_string())
          Type          Value PeriodBeginDate PeriodEndDate  Instance0MetricType  Instance0Count   Instance1MetricType  Instance1Count                        Title Platform                                     Publisher
0  Proprietary     Ovid:21790      2019-02-01    2019-02-28  Total_Item_Requests             1.0  Unique_Item_Requests             1.0  AACN Advanced Critical Care   OvidMD  American Association of Critical Care Nurses
1  Proprietary  Ovid:01256961             NaN           NaN                  NaN             NaN                   NaN             NaN  AACN Advanced Critical Care   OvidMD  American Association of Critical Care Nurses
```